# How to display Hourly Weather data based on Current Hour?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my weather project, I have hourly weather data. To get a particular city hourly data it needs the timezone that has current timing and then it can display data based on that hour. See below code for better understanding.

HourlyForecast.js

```
export class HourlyForecast extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {};  
    }
    render() {
        const { data } = this.props;       

        if(!data) return null; 
        const time = data.datetime
        const time2 = time.slice(11,13)
        console.log('HOURLY DATA', time2)

        const time5  = moment.tz(this.props.timezone).format('HH:mm').slice(0,2)
        console.log('TIME CURRENT', time5);
    }
}

export default HourlyForecast
```

I get both values i.e Hourly Time as well as Current Time. I want to display data based on current hour of the particular city input. Like for e.g In London, UK current time is 04 AM and Hourly data that ranges from 02 - 22 (From 2 AM till 10 PM). Now I want to display Weather data from 04 - 09 (From 04 AM till 09 AM). How to do it?

[image]
See above image for reference.The data is of Moscow, Russia. Hourly data I get from weather API ranges from 00 to 09 and current timing hour is 02. So how to match with hourly data and show only 5 elements i.e 02 to 07. Any suggestion highly appreciated.

Sample JSON data

```
DATA HOURLY {"data":[{"wind_cdir":"SSE","rh":97,"pod":"d","timestamp_utc":"2019-11-29T07:00:00","pres":991.986,"solar_rad":8.646,"ozone":239.927,"weather":{"icon":"s05d","code":611,"description":"Sleet"},"wind_gust_spd":6.99104,"timestamp_local":"2019-11-29T10:00:00","snow_depth":1,"clouds":100,"ts":1575010800,"wind_spd":2.9362,"pop":15,"wind_cdir_full":"south-southeast","slp":1010.18,"dni":400.98,"dewpt":-0.3,"snow":0.499994,"uv":0.733082,"wind_dir":157,"clouds_hi":6,"precip":0.1015625,"vis":24.1352,"dhi":44.95,"app_temp":-4.8,"datetime":"2019-11-29:07","temp":0.1,"ghi":86.46,"clouds_mid":0,"clouds_low":100},{"wind_cdir":"SSE","rh":97,"pod":"d","timestamp_utc":"2019-11-29T08:00:00","pres":991.621,"solar_rad":14.544,"ozone":237.329,"weather":{"icon":"s05d","code":611,"description":"Sleet"},"wind_gust_spd":7.2302,"timestamp_local":"2019-11-29T11:00:00","snow_depth":1,"clouds":100,"ts":1575014400,"wind_spd":3.02753,"pop":15,"wind_cdir_full":"south-southeast","slp":1009.79,"dni":514.77,"dewpt":-0.2,"snow":0.0676169,"uv":0.754683,"wind_dir":157,"clouds_hi":45,"precip":0.01123046875,"vis":24.1348,"dhi":56.99,"app_temp":-4.6,"datetime":"2019-11-29:08","temp":0.3,"ghi":145.44,"clouds_mid":0,"clouds_low":100},{"wind_cdir":"SSE","rh":98,"pod":"d","timestamp_utc":"2019-11-29T09:00:00","pres":991.014,"solar_rad":17.402,"ozone":239.801,"weather":{"icon":"c04d","code":803,"description":"Overcast clouds"},"wind_gust_spd":7.35617,"timestamp_local":"2019-11-29T12:00:00","snow_depth":1,"clouds":100,"ts":1575018000,"wind_spd":3.0718,"pop":0,"wind_cdir_full":"south-southeast","slp":1009.17,"dni":556.24,"dewpt":0,"snow":0,"uv":0.765051,"wind_dir":153,"clouds_hi":91,"precip":0,"vis":24.1347,"dhi":61.75,"app_temp":-4.3,"datetime":"2019-11-29:09","temp":0.5,"ghi":174.02,"clouds_mid":5,"clouds_low":100},{"wind_cdir":"SSE","rh":97,"pod":"d","timestamp_utc":"2019-11-29T10:00:00","pres":990.086,"solar_rad":16.655,"ozone":241.9,"weather":{"icon":"c04d","code":803,"description":"Overcast clouds"},"wind_gust_spd":8.48581,"timestamp_local":"2019-11-29T13:00:00","snow_depth":0.9,"clouds":100,"ts":1575021600,"wind_spd":3.54776,"pop":0,"wind_cdir_full":"south-southeast","slp":1008.2,"dni":546.02,"dewpt":0.4,"snow":0,"uv":0.758712,"wind_dir":156,"clouds_hi":100,"precip":0,"vis":24.1352,"dhi":60.55,"app_temp":-3.9,"datetime":"2019-11-29:10","temp":0.8,"ghi":166.55,"clouds_mid":77,"clouds_low":100},{"wind_cdir":"SSE","rh":97,"pod":"d","timestamp_utc":"2019-11-29T11:00:00","pres":989.655,"solar_rad":12.441,"ozone":243.157,"weather":{"icon":"c04d","code":803,"description":"Overcast clouds"},"wind_gust_spd":8.51729,"timestamp_local":"2019-11-29T14:00:00","snow_depth":0.8,"clouds":100,"ts":1575025200,"wind_spd":3.46162,"pop":15,"wind_cdir_full":"south-southeast","slp":1007.74,"dni":479.49,"dewpt":0.5,"snow":0,"uv":0.739715,"wind_dir":155,"clouds_hi":90,"precip":0.0009765625,"vis":24.135,"dhi":53.1,"app_temp":-3.7,"datetime":"2019-11-29:11","temp":1,"ghi":124.41,"clouds_mid":100,"clouds_low":100},{"wind_cdir":"SSE","rh":97,"pod":"d","timestamp_utc":"2019-11-29T12:00:00","pres":989.567,"solar_rad":5.697,"ozone":243.842,"weather":{"icon":"c04d","code":803,"description":"Overcast clouds"},"wind_gust_spd":8.7108,"timestamp_local":"2019-11-29T15:00:00","snow_depth":0.7,"clouds":100,"ts":1575028800,"wind_spd":3.64744,"pop":0,"wind_cdir_full":"south-southeast","slp":1007.63,"dni":318.85,"dewpt":0.6,"snow":0,"uv":0.723368,"wind_dir":155,"clouds_hi":67,"precip":0,"vis":24.1347,"dhi":36.99,"app_temp":-3.5,"datetime":"2019-11-29:12","temp":1.1,"ghi":56.97,"clouds_mid":90,"clouds_low":100},{"wind_cdir":"SSE","rh":96,"pod":"n","timestamp_utc":"2019-11-29T13:00:00","pres":989.334,"solar_rad":0,"ozone":246.029,"weather":{"icon":"c04n","code":803,"description":"Overcast clouds"},"wind_gust_spd":9.00091,"timestamp_local":"2019-11-29T16:00:00","snow_depth":0.6,"clouds":100,"ts":1575032400,"wind_spd":3.77559,"pop":0,"wind_cdir_full":"south-southeast","slp":1007.39,"dni":0,"dewpt":0.6,"snow":0,"uv":0,"wind_dir":156,"clouds_hi":65,"precip":0,"vis":24.1349,"dhi":0.25,"app_temp":-3.4,"datetime":"2019-11-29:13","temp":1.2,"ghi":0,"clouds_mid":79,"clouds_low":100},{"wind_cdir":"SSE","rh":97,"pod":"n","timestamp_utc":"2019-11-29T14:00:00","pres":988.535,"solar_rad":0,"ozone":249.188,"weather":{"icon":"c04n","code":803,"description":"Overcast clouds"},"wind_gust_spd":9.57769,"timestamp_local":"2019-11-29T17:00:00","snow_depth":0.5,"clouds":100,"ts":1575036000,"wind_spd":4.034,"pop":0,"wind_cdir_full":"south-southeast","slp":1006.58,"dni":0,"dewpt":0.6,"snow":0,"uv":0,"wind_dir":152,"clouds_hi":15,"precip":0,"vis":24.135,"dhi":0,"app_temp":-3.5,"datetime":"2019-11-29:14","temp":1.1,"ghi":0,"clouds_mid":84,"clouds_low":100},{"wind_cdir":"SSE","rh":97,"pod":"n","timestamp_utc":"2019-11-29T15:00:00","pres":987.8,"solar_rad":0,"ozone":248.493,"weather":{"icon":"c04n","code":803,"description":"Overcast clouds"},"wind_gust_spd":9.95356,"timestamp_local":"2019-11-29T18:00:00","snow_depth":0.4,"clouds":100,"ts":1575039600,"wind_spd":4.16085,"pop":0,"wind_cdir_full":"south-southeast","slp":1005.83,"dni":0,"dewpt":0.7,"snow":0,"uv":0,"wind_dir":153,"clouds_hi":100,"precip":0,"vis":24.1351,"dhi":0,"app_temp":-3.5,"datetime":"2019-11-29:15","temp":1.1,"ghi":0,"clouds_mid":80,"clouds_low":98},{"wind_cdir":"SSE","rh":97,"pod":"n","timestamp_utc":"2019-11-29T16:00:00","pres":987.123,"solar_rad":0,"ozone":249.409,"weather":{"icon":"c04n","code":803,"description":"Overcast clouds"},"wind_gust_spd":10.4871,"timestamp_local":"2019-11-29T19:00:00","snow_depth":0.4,"clouds":98,"ts":1575043200,"wind_spd":4.36438,"pop":15,"wind_cdir_full":"south-southeast","slp":1005.15,"dni":0,"dewpt":0.7,"snow":0,"uv":0,"wind_dir":149,"clouds_hi":29,"precip":0.00390625,"vis":24.135,"dhi":0,"app_temp":-3.5,"datetime":"2019-11-29:16","temp":1.1,"ghi":0,"clouds_mid":87,"clouds_low":93}],"city_name":"Moscow","lon":"37.61556","timezone":"Europe/Moscow","lat":"55.75222","country_code":"RU","state_code":"48"}
```

Comment: is your API to get weather data can provide historic data?

Comment: Yes this API also has historic data available

Comment: okay. what do you mean by display data based on current hour of the particular city input. did you mean the current timezone of that city/area?

Comment: Hi @Meraki, well take for e.g time at London is now 3 AM which is Current time hour, and hourly data's (i.e weather info shown per hour)  hour ranges from 00 AM (midnight) till 10 AM, now I want show data from 03 to 10 AM (i.e 03, 04, 05, 06.... 10 hour interval)

Comment: timezone is required to get current time of particular city inputted

Comment: can you provide sample json data coming from the API

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203298/discussion-between-pranav-and-meraki).